# How can I transform my .tsx files into the .jsx syntax expected by ReactJS.NET?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs, reactjs.net

I am using [ReactJS.NET](https://reactjs.net/). I can get the [React.Sample.Webpack](https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET) demo working but I want to modify it to use TypeScript.

The ultimate error is thrown from the `@Html.React("Components.Temp", new { })` html helper in `Index.cshtml`.
Here is the error message:

> Error while rendering "Components.Temp" to "react_3FYDPtcTMkKrddTO7ozOCA": Script threw an exception: Element type is invalid: expected a string  (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)  but got: object.

## The problem

The .jsx files used in the demo project end with the following statements:

```
module.exports = Avatar; // From Avatar.jsx
module.exports = Comment; // From Comment.jsx
module.exports = CommentsBox; // From CommentsBox.jsx
```

Notice the use of `module.exports`. The code generated by tsc has this instead:

```
exports.default = Temp; // From Temp.jsx
exports.default = TempImport; // From TempImport.jsx
```

In addition, in the tsc generated .jsx files, imported components have a `default` property added to them. From the `Temp.jsx` file below:

```
render() {
    return (<TempImport_1.default />);
}
```

Notice the `default` appended to `TempImport_1`

If I manually alter the tsc generated .jsx files to use `modules.export = Temp` and `<TempImport />`, everything works.

## The Question(s)

1. How can I generate a .jsx file that can be consumed by the ReactJS.NET Html helper?
2. Are there settings in `tsconfig.json` for this?
3. Are there loaders I can add to `webpack.config.js` that will take care of this?

## Edits

If I remove `export default` from class definition in the .tsx file and manually add `module.exports = ComponentName` at the end, the resulting .jsx file has `module.exports` as well. However, `default` is still added to the end of all imported components. See "Attempt 2" code at the end of this post.

## The relevant files

**TempImport.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";

export default class TempImport extends React.Component<undefined, undefined> {
    render() {
        return (<h1>Temp Import</h1>);
    }
}
```

**Temp.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import TempImport from "./TempImport";

export default class Temp extends React.Component<undefined, undefined> {
    render() {
        return (<TempImport />);
    }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "outDir": "./Content/components",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es6"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

**TempImport.jsx (Generated by tsc)**

```
const React = require("react");
class TempImport extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<h1>Temp Import</h1>);
    }
}
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.default = TempImport;
```

**Temp.jsx (Generated by tsc)**

```
const React = require("react");
const TempImport_1 = require("./TempImport");
class Temp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<TempImport_1.default />);
    }
}
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.default = Temp;
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, "Content"),
    entry: {
        server: "./server",
        client: "./client"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
        filename: "[name].bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loaders: ["babel-loader"],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
    },
    externals: {
        react: "React"
    }
};
```

**Temp.tsx (Attempt 2)**

Notice I have removed `export default` and added `module.exports = Temp`

```
import * as React from "react";
import TempImport from "./TempImport";

class Temp extends React.Component<undefined, undefined> {
    render() {
        return (<TempImport />);
    }
}

module.exports = Temp;
```

**Temp.jsx (Attempt 2 - generated by tsc)**

Notice it now has `module.exports = Temp` at the bottom but `<TempImport_1` still has `default` appended to it.

```
const React = require("react");
const TempImport_1 = require("./TempImport");
class Temp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<TempImport_1.default />);
    }
}
module.exports = Temp;
```

Comment: Are all of those `module.exports` lines in the same file?

Comment: They are in separate files. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Try changing `target` to `"ES5"` in `tsconfig.json`. `exports.default` is an ES6 conversion thing (it's how the compiler handles default exports), it just might not be playing together nicely with Babel.

Comment: The resulting .jsx file still appends .default to the end of all components =(

Comment: It appends .default because you export it as defaults. Look here `export default class Temp` you have keyword `default`. For me the generated code looks good. It should have `.default` keyword. I think that the problem  is somewhere else